# PHP sorting arrays by subarray key groups

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to group elements of variable array called $list with subarrays with random subarray order like:

```
$list = array(
    1 => array('number' => 1),
    2 => array('title' => 'Title One'),
    3 => array('text' => 'Text One'),

    4 => array('title' => 'Title Two'),
    5 => array('number' => 2),
    6 => array('text' => 'Text Two'),

    7 => array('text' => 'Text Three'),
    8 => array('title' => 'Title Three'),
    9 => array('number' => 3),
);
```

How can I group them into

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 1
            [title] => Title One
            [text] => Text One
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title Two
            [number] => 2
            [text] => Text Two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => Text Three
            [title] => Title Three
            [number] => 3
        )

)
```

Important Note:

1. The subarray keys can be any string, not just 'title', 'text', 'number'. Meaning I can have 1 or more elements, it's not predefined to 3 ('title', 'text', 'number') in this case.
2. The result order within each [0], [1], [2]... groups doesn't matter as long as they are grouped together.

Comment: go back to the source and return meaningful data

Comment: If it's in completely random order, then absent some dictionary to tell it which `number`, `title`, and `text` elements are linked, you can't.

Comment: Are there any bounds to this information? Do certain title's belong to certain numbers, etc?

Comment: @rosscowar Each subarray for example array('title' => 'Title One') is a line in a text file.

Comment: How is the program supposed to know that Title `One` belongs to Number `1` and Text `One`?

Comment: Also @Dagon is right, you should provide some source of the actual problem at hand it would be very beneficial.

Comment: @rosscowar I have added additional info above. The data is read from a text file to be displayed on a web page.

Comment: after edit - so what's with the 2nd $list array and random order, that makes no sense

Comment: Ok so the binding information grouping this information is their position in the text file. What's the need to sort stuff if it comes in randomly?

Comment: @Dagon It's because I can't predict the exact order the user is going to create the data in a text file (added additional info above), thanks!

Comment: instruct user to do it in order.

Comment: @rosscowar I guess I've misused the word "sorting" , because grouping is the core feature that I need, it doesn't matter how it is sorted within the subarray group in $results.

Comment: @Dagon It won't be possible to instruct user to do it in order, because the result of $list is from a list that might not contain arrays (I was able to narrow down to $list into an array).

Comment: The data in your example text file is already “grouped” – so all you would have to do is read three lines each, extract the data and put it into an array … and then read over the blank lines, and start again with the next three lines of data …

Comment: sigh, can i have my 10 minutes back please?

Comment: Ok well I'm sure this issue is very simple but it's not so much an issue with reading / parsing / sorting data. It sounds more like an issue of improperly inputting data. In weird situations like this it would be more beneficial to provide a live example of what you're talking about as opposed to a hypothetical one.

Comment: GIGO.  It looks like the best you can hope for is to build your array by order of appearance in text file and *assume* they match up.

Comment: @CrayonViolent agreed. If you can't control the order these fragments come you need to prepend or append some sort of unique key that will be omitted later on to let you organize them appropriately. There are a lot of ways to do this and he's right Garbage In is Garbage Out.

Comment: I don't understand how you are arriving at that 2nd `$list` example anyways.. in *both* of your txt file examples, the title, text and number *are* grouped. If that's really how it is in your txt file, then you must be doing some bad logic to arrive at your 2nd `$list` example..

Comment: @crayon-violent I was able to arrive at $list and $list2 to separate them, now I just need to process the problem posted here. I didn't post other info so it will not get distracted from the core problem I am trying to solve and explain here, thanks.

Comment: @user702300 I understand, but as you can see, what you've presented has yielded nothing but everybody telling you that you're SoL. So, either you need to back up and focus on what you are *starting* with, or, well, continue to be SoL. Because there is a clear disconnect between what you are showing that you're starting with and the arrays you have arrived at. If you are able to get that first `$list` then putting them into `$results` like you want is easy. But then you say it's sometimes in the order of the 2nd `$list` and that's not consistent with the source you listed.

Comment: It looks like the going off topic, so I have changed and updated the question by only focusing on the feature I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out ,

array_chunk($list,3,true);

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$keyCount = array();
$finalArray = array();

foreach($list as $value) {
    $temp = key($value);
    $currentKey = $temp[0];
    $count = isset($keyCount[$currentKey]) ? $keyCount[$currentKey]: 0;
    $keyCount[$currentKey] = $count + 1;
    $finalArray[$count] = isset($finalArray[$count]) ? $finalArray[$count] : array();
    $finalArray[$count][$currentKey] = $value[$currentKey];
}
```